# apk not generated because of error in dependency

Tags: android, dependencies, admob, apk

Below is my app level gradle file.

```
dependencies 
    {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
}
```

This was working fine until I added the last dependency. Since then apk is not generated.

Below is the build output

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-23:19 to override.

I tried changing the

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1

to **11.0.0**
This helped me in generating the apk, but with a warning that 'All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specifications (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)'

I am completely unaware about this, so wasn't able to take help from other such questions and asked it directly.

Is it ok if I deploy it on playstore with that warning?
Or is there some way I can get rid of it with '19.0.1'?

Comment: I had the same problem with ad dependency. If you don't need it, you can comment it.

Comment: No @MohammadMoeinGolchin, this was raising other errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code at the bottom of your project level `build.gradle` and sync your project

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "19.0.1"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it asked me to add 4 dependencies.     `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:19.0.1'`

Comment: and when I added these, I got the error    `ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-23:19 to override.`

Comment: You need to migrate your support libraries to AndroidX libraries. That may help

Comment: Yes, i migrated to AndroidX and its works with 19.0.1.